# Relation between simple roots and idempotents of quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, idempotents

Given a ring $A$ and a polynomial $p\in A[x]$, write $Z(p,A)$ for the *simple* roots in $A$ of $p\in A[x]$. On the other hand, consider the set $\mathrm{Idemp}(A[x]/(p))$ of idempotents of the quotient.

What's the relation between $Z(p,A),\mathrm{Idemp}(A[x]/(p))$? (Perhaps assuming $p$ is monic?) Are the simple roots perhaps in bijection with the connected components of $(A[x]/(p))$?

Given a simple root $\alpha\in A$ of $p$ I thought to look at $(x-\alpha)\in A[x]$ and use the Chinese remainder theorem...

If there isn't a "pointwise" relation, perhaps the following properties of the quotient $A\twoheadrightarrow A/I$ are equivalent?

1. For each (monic?) $p\in A[x]$ the set-function $Z(p,A){\longrightarrow} Z(\overline p,\frac AI)$ is surjective.
2. For each (monic?) $p\in A[x]$ the boolean algebra morphism $\mathrm{idemp}(A[x]/(p))\to \mathrm{idemp}(\frac AI[x]/(\overline p))$ is surjective.
3. <s>For each (monic?) $p\in A[x]$ the analogous set function between *connected components* is surjective.</s>

**Update.** As answered by Mohan, the simple roots are certainly not in bijection with connected components. The question remains about the equivalence of (1) and (2) above.

Comment: If $p=x-a$ I can't see any connection. Do you?

Comment: Dear @user26857, I certainly don't see anything you don't. I ask because [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1085270/223002) there is a characterization of Henselian local rings via induced bijection on idempotents, while in example 6.1 [here](https://ncatlab.org/joyalscatlab/published/Factorisation+systems#in_algebra) it's claimed that being Henselian is also equivalent to inducing a bijection between simple roots.

Comment: Example 6.2....

Comment: @user26857 ah yes, sorry!

Comment: Dear @user26857, it seems Lemma 10.1.9 in the book *Separable Algebras* by Ford proves (rather indirectly) that condition (2) in my question implies condition (1). (I think lifts of simple roots in the residue field are simple in the local ring.) I have no idea about the converse.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ are irreducible and coprime of degree at least 2 and $p=fg$, then $p$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$, but the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x]/p(x)$ is not connected and has two connected components.

Comment: Dear Mohan, thank you for your answer. I think I have read conditions that 1,2 are equivalent (also to $(A, I)$ being a Henselian pair). What do you think?

Comment: Dear Mohan, I linked to the assertions which I'd like to understand in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053894/relation-between-simple-roots-and-idempotents-of-quotient-ring?noredirect=1#comment6296417_3053894).